# Error in lseek when I am trying to create holes in file

Tags: c, unix

I have written the below program to create a file containing holes but I am getting an error in lseek() as below:
Error in lseek <22> : Invalid argument
I just want to write "1" at first and "2" at 100th offset. I have tried it with SEEK_END also, but no success

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {

    int fd = -1;
    int rc = -1;
    char *buff = "1";
    char *buff_end = "2";
    char *err;

    fd = open("hole_file", O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_TRUNC, 0644);

    if (fd == -1) {
        printf("\n Error in open() !!!");
        return (-1);
    }

    rc = write(fd, buff, sizeof(buff));
    if (rc == -1) {
        printf("\n Error in writing at start location <%d>", errno);
        close(fd);
        unlink("hole_file");
        return (-1);
    }

    rc = lseek(fd, SEEK_CUR, 100);
    if (rc == -1) {
        err = strerror(errno);
        printf("\n Error in lseek <%d> : %s\n", errno, err);
        close(fd);
        unlink("hole_file");
        return (-1);
    }


    rc = write(fd, buff_end, sizeof(buff_end));
    if (rc == -1) {
        printf("\n Error in writing at 100th offset <%d>", errno);
        close(fd);
        unlink("hole_file");
        return (-1);
    }

    close(fd);

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Aside from the wrong lseek parameters, there is a bug in using `sizeof (buff)` which is the size of the **pointer** (likely 4 or 8) and not the length of the string, as you seem to intend.

Comment: Use `0666` instead of `0644` - reducing that is the umask's job.

Answer (score 4):

You've swapped the arguments.

```
lseek(fd, SEEK_CUR, 100)
```

should be

```
lseek(fd, 100, SEEK_CUR)
```

Answer (score 0):

After

```
rc = write(fd, buff, sizeof(buff));
```

you have the pointer at end of file, you can't use SEEK_CUR, you must use SEEK_SET, and you put the lseek flag at wrong position in parameter list:

```
rc = lseek(fd, 100, SEEK_SET);
```

Comment: why shouldn't it be possible to use `SEEK_CUR`? I can advance the file pointer by 99 and be at 100. `rc = lseek(fd, 99, SEEK_CUR);`

Comment: the asker is opening file with O_TRUNC which will make the file empty. then write to it before calling lseek, this makes the file pointer be at the end of file

Comment: Up to there, right. But that doesn't hurt - the result is a file with length 1. So `lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_CUR)` is equivalent to  `lseek(fd, 1, SEEK_SET)` and `lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END)` etc.